# Selecting last value in a colum without null value

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a SQL SELECT Statement situation as follows:

I want to select and get the row with `Aquila's` Test2 mark which is `30` as the last value under the mark column and omit the null rows. In other words, I want to group the students by Test# and select the latest test mark that is not null. Data should be Sorted by Test# DESC Order.

How do I achieve this? Please help.

My table looks like this:

```
+------------+-------------+
ID| Test# | Student | Mark |
+------------+-------------+
1 | Test1 | Aquila  | 20   |
2 | Test1 | Peter   | 30   |
3 | Test1 | Jack    | 40   |
4 | Test2 | Aquila  | 30   |
5 | Test2 | PETER   | 40   |
6 | Test2 | Jack    | 50   |
7 | Test3 | Aquila  | NULL |
8 | Test3 | Peter   | 50   |
9 | Test3 | Jack    | 60   |
+------------+-------------+
```

I want the output to be:

```
+------------+-------------+
ID| Test# | Student | Mark |
+------------+-------------+
4 | Test2 | Aquila  | 30   |
8 | Test3 | Peter   | 50   |
9 | Test3 | Jack    | 60   |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What is the logic by which `Aquila` would be last here? Do you have a column on which we can sort the data that `Aquila` would be last?

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the absence of an ORDER BY clause, 'last value' has no meaning.

Comment: I have now edited and update my question. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: It's still a little unclear. Please show a second table of what you want to the result to be, exactly. How do you define the "latest" mark? There's no date or time associated with the records.

Comment: I updated the question with a second table for the output. Please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Students
where Mark is not NULL 
order by Mark desc
```

//the `desc` `order by` assumes knowledge of the data

Comment: This statement is ok but it selects all and not only the last. Say for example, in the above table it outputs both Aquila 20 and Aquila 30. What I want is Aquila 30 only which is the last record with value, not null.

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked out the select statement myself as follows and it worked. If someone out there has a similar problem, here is the working code.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT MAX(ID) 
FROM table WHERE mark IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Test# DESC);
```