# Oracle - Min value grouping by range of records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

To exemplify, suppose I have the following values in a table:

```
---------------------------------------
|    ID_USER    |     START_DATE      |
---------------------------------------
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:00:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:15:00 |
|       2       | 01/01/2018 08:30:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:45:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 09:00:00 |
|       2       | 01/01/2018 09:15:00 |
|       2       | 01/01/2018 09:30:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 09:45:00 |
---------------------------------------
```

Now I would like to group by ID_USER, selecting the minimun START_DATE value as long as they are correlatives. The solution would be:

```
---------------------------------------
|    ID_USER    |     START_DATE      |
---------------------------------------
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:00:00 |
|       2       | 01/01/2018 08:30:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:45:00 |
|       2       | 01/01/2018 09:15:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 09:45:00 |
---------------------------------------
```

Have you got any idea how can I make this query?

Comment: [Check this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655055/selecting-last-value-in-a-colum-without-null-value/54731697#54731697) I will help you solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Compare current and previous row using `LAG`:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select  ID_USER, START_DATE,
      lag(ID_USER, 1, -1) over (order by START_DATE) as prev_user
   from myTable
 )
select *
from cte
where ID_USER <>  prev_user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with s (id_user, start_date) as (
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 08:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 08:15:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('01/01/2018 08:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 08:45:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 09:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('01/01/2018 09:15:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('01/01/2018 09:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 09:45:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
select id_user, start_date
from
   (select s.*, lag(id_user) over (order by start_date) prev_user
    from s
   )
where lnnvl(prev_user = id_user);

   ID_USER START_DATE
---------- -------------------
         1 2018-01-01 08:00:00
         2 2018-01-01 08:30:00
         1 2018-01-01 08:45:00
         2 2018-01-01 09:15:00
         1 2018-01-01 09:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Oracle 12c+: Pattern matching
with s (id_user, start_date) as (
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 08:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 08:15:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('01/01/2018 08:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 08:45:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 09:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('01/01/2018 09:15:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('01/01/2018 09:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('01/01/2018 09:45:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
select id_user, start_date
from s
match_recognize(
order by start_date
measures
   id_user    as id_user,
   start_date as start_date
pattern (v+)
define v as id_user = first(id_user)
);

   ID_USER START_DATE
---------- -------------------
         1 2018-01-01 08:15:00
         2 2018-01-01 08:30:00
         1 2018-01-01 09:00:00
         2 2018-01-01 09:30:00
         1 2018-01-01 09:45:00
```